# how to change the email or password of user as admin in aws amplify for node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Everyone.
I am developing using react app with aws amplify.
For user authentication, I am using aws cognito.
After I create user account by admin account on cognito, I can't change email and password of user as admin on there yet.
How can I do for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the below way. But make sure that while configuring the cognito, the below fields[fields that you want to change] are set Mutable. Please follow these two links they might help more ([Congito Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html)) & ([adminUpdateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html)).

```
var params = {
  UserPoolId: '',//YOUR UserPoolID
  Username: '',//username
  UserAttributes: [
    {
      Name: "email",
      Value: ``,//NEW Email
    },
    {
      Name: "name",
      Value: ``,//New Name
    },
    {
      Name: "phone_number",
      Value: ``,//New Phone
    },
  ],
};
const cognitoClient = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
var createPromise = cognitoClient.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params).promise();
await createPromise;
```